# Print a matrix in VBA

Tags: vba, excel

[For example please open this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TxiWf.jpg)If there is N*N matrix as R(row) is given. So the program will find the minimum value in Rth row and then replace that particular column with 9999. I am getting #value error. How to rectify this?
I think there is some error in defining an array.
Please help me in this.

```
Function abc(N As Range, R As Integer) As Range
    Dim c As Integer, i As Integer, min As Integer, ci As Integer, a As Integer,
    j As Integer, y As Integer, z As Integer

    a = N.Rows.Count
    c = N.Columns.Count

    Dim ab(1 To 1000, 1 To 1000) As integer

    min = N(R, 1)
    ci = 1

    For i = 1 To c
        If N(R, i) < min Then
            min = N(R, i) And ci = i
        End If
    Next i

    For y = 1 To a
        For z = 1 To c
            If z = ci Then
                ab(y, z) = 9999
            Else
                ab(y, z) = N(y, z)
            End If
        Next z
    Next y

    abc = ab
End Function
```

Comment: You aren't returning a `Range` for a start... so change your first line to `Function abc(N As Range, R As Integer) As Variant`

Comment: Returning a variant to the worksheet requires entering as a CSE array formula to view the results

Comment: Why do you declare fixed array when you obviously have bounds for both dimensions?

Comment: Please don't change your question once it is answered.

Answer (score 0):

Does this need to be VBA? Can be done with this formula (using your sample image, put this formula in cell D1 and copy over and down):

```
=IF(COLUMN(A1)=MATCH(MIN(INDEX($A$1:$B$2,2,0)),INDEX($A$1:$B$2,2,0),0),5432,INDEX($A$1:$B$2,ROW(A1),COLUMN(A1)))
```

- Change both instances of `$A$1:$B$2` to be the actual range the formula should be evaulating
- Change `5432` to be the number you actually want returned (I got 5432 from your sample image, but your UDF shows 9999)

Answer (score 0):

other than the output issue, your code is not consequent to your question wording

so either you

- have to substitute the minimum value in a row with 9999

  so your code can be reduced to

  ```
  Function abc(N As Range, R As Integer) As Variant
      Dim a As Long, c As Long, j As Long, min As Long, cj As Long

      Dim ab As Variant
      ab = N.value

      a = UBound(ab, 1)
      c = UBound(ab, 2)

      min = ab(R, 1)
      cj = 1
      For j = 1 To c
          If ab(R, j) < min Then
              min = ab(R, j)
              cj = j
          End If
      Next

      ab(R, cj) = 9999

      abc = ab
  End Function
  ```
- or you have to change ALL the range cells whose content matches the given row minimum value to this latter

  ```
  Function abc2(N As Range, R As Integer) As Variant
      Dim a As Long, c As Long, i As Long, j As Long, min As Long

      Dim ab As Variant
      ab = N.value

      a = UBound(ab, 1)
      c = UBound(ab, 2)

      min = ab(R, 1)
      For j = 1 To c
          If ab(R, j) < min Then min = ab(R, j)
      Next

      For i = 1 To a
          For j = 1 To c
              If ab(i, j) = min Then ab(i, j) = 9999
          Next
      Next

      abc2 = ab
  End Function
  ```